# Action method not being called on second, third h:commandbutton after first button is clicked in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I have a JSF page that I intend on using to edit a user's information. All of the components needed for editing the user are included in the same pag an dI'm using the render attribute to determine which components should be rendered. The first panel group is rendered and when you enter the users login name and click the button everything works just fine and the second panel group is displayed and you can change the users information in the text fields. The problem comes in with the clicking the button in the first tab of the accordian panel, it doesn't work. I've tried request scope and view scope and have the same problem when using either one.

```
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" />
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title></title>
        </f:facet> 
    </h:head>
    <h:body styleClass="pageDefaultBGC">
            <p:layout fullPage="true">
                <f:facet name="last">
                    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="discovery.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
                </f:facet>
                <p:layoutUnit styleClass="headerDiv" position="north" size="100">
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="header.jpg"></h:graphicImage>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit styleClass="navDiv" position="west" size="200">
                    <h:outputText value="Navigation Menu"></h:outputText>
                    <br/>
                    <hr/>
                    <h:outputLink styleClass="navLink" value="index.xhtml">Admin Home</h:outputLink>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLink styleClass="navLink" value="addNewUser.xhtml">Add New User</h:outputLink>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLink styleClass="navLink" value="edituser.xhtml">Edit User</h:outputLink>
                    <br/>                    
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="main">
                    <h:form id="editForm">
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!adminManagedBean.editingUser}">
                            <h2>Edit User Account</h2>
                            <h:outputLabel for="useredit" value="Enter User's Name:"></h:outputLabel>
                            <h:inputText id="useredit" value="#{adminManagedBean.editUserLogin}" required="true"></h:inputText>
                            <br/><br/>                  
      THIS BUTTON WORKS!---><h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{adminManagedBean.startUserEdit()}"></h:commandButton>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{adminManagedBean.editingUser}">
                            <h:outputText value="Editing User:"></h:outputText>
                            <p:dataTable value="#{adminManagedBean.editUser}" var="u">
                                <p:column styleClass="dataTableHeader" headerText="Full Name">#{u.firstName}&nbsp;#{u.lastName}</p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="dataTableHeader" headerText="Username">#{u.login}</p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="dataTableHeader" headerText="Phone">#{u.phone}</p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="dataTableHeader" headerText="Email">#{u.email}</p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="dataTableHeader" headerText="Agency ID">#{u.agencyId}</p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                            <br/>
                            <h:outputText value="User's Current Roles"></h:outputText>
                            <ul>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{adminManagedBean.editUsersRoles}" var="cr">
                                    <li><h:outputText value="#{cr}"></h:outputText></li>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </ul>
                            <br/>
                            <h:outputText value="Select an item to edit using the menu below"></h:outputText>
                            <br/>
                            <p:accordionPanel>
                                    <p:tab title="Edit User's Name" titleStyleClass="accordianTitleStyle">
                                            <h:panelGrid styleClass="panelGridStyle1" columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                                                <h:outputText value="First Name:"></h:outputText>
                                                <h:inputText value="#{adminManagedBean.editUser.firstName}"></h:inputText>
                                                <h:outputText value="Last Name:"></h:outputText>
                                                <h:inputText value="#{adminManagedBean.editUser.lastName}"></h:inputText>
                  THIS BUTTON DOESN'T WORK----><h:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="#{adminManagedBean.saveNameChange()}"></h:commandButton>
                                                <h:commandButton value="Cancel Changes"></h:commandButton>    
                                            </h:panelGrid>
                                    </p:tab>
```

The command button with the value "Save Changes" is the button in question since the bean method is never called.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AdminManagedBean implements Serializable {
public String saveNameChange(){
    log.info("save Name called");
    this.editUser = ssb.updateUser(editUser);
    return "edituser";
}
```

The method "saveNameChange" is not being called when the button is clicked. Any help wouldbe greatly appreciated.

Comment: is all those code necessary for reproducing bug?

Comment: No it is not complete enough to run and reproduce. In order for that to be possible you would need to be able to create a persistence unit for the underlying database. I placed the code in the xhtml page up to the point where the method that should be being called is not being called and that particular method in the bean.

Comment: I see your code and get lost between all that non-related JSF code. At least add a comment in your JSF code showing the button that *doesn't work*.

Comment: added "THIS BUTTON WORKS--->" to the button that works and "THIS BUTTON DOESN'T WORK----->" to the button that doesn't work.

Comment: Please, learn how to isolate the problem and create an [SSCCE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). For instance, is the `<hr/>` in the code absolutely necessary in order for us to reproduce your  problem by copypasting the code into a blank playground environment? If not, then it's just pure noise. And you seem to have a lot of it, causing us to not immediately see the tree in the forest, and therefore not willing to spend the effort finding it. The same applies to some JSF tags such as `<p:layoutUnit>`, `<h:outputText>`, etc.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. In the process of re-creating the page and bean for use in posting the question like you asked I discovered the cause of the problem.

Comment: @ChadNC please post the fix for other people to see.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of editing the page and bean for posting on S.O. the problem was discovered and it had nothing to do with the JSF components. The problem was two fold,

1) A developer had changed the size of a field in a table in the db but not in the entity class associated with that table which was causing validation to throw an error message.
2) The styling being used was preventing the error message from the validation from being displayed.

Solution: I updated the entity class, corrected the styling and the buttons are now working properly.